# 'Interiors of these houses' or 'interior of these houses'?

Tags: grammatical-number

If 'interior' is not wrong (or even preferred), then how about 'wife of these men' (instead of 'wives of these men')?

Comment: This would depend on whether you wish to use a countable or uncountable noun. L

Comment: Although I must say I like "wife of these men" a lot. It's witty.

Comment: Do you have something against polyandry?

Comment: Interior if the houses have the same one, interiors if they are different. Same with wives.

Comment: "wife of these men'?  what society are we talking about?